# Flexbox - how to align left the last flex item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Do you have an idea how to align the last string in flexbox block?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.wrapper p {
  flex: auto;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
  <p>D</p>
  <p>E</p>
  <p>F</p>
  <p>G</p>
  <p>H</p>
  <p>I</p>
  <p>J</p>
</div>
```

Everything works fine but the last string breaks blocks not as good as I wanted. On the screenshot below you can see behavior of the block and my red notes how I wanted.

[image]

Thanks a lot for any help!

-- EDITED --

Sorry, I didn't specify that I wanted save full width of wrapper tag. If I remove **flex: auto;** from child blocks it became not full width https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrzCV.png

Comment: Set flex grow to 0 for the `p`s if you want to keep that `flex: auto`

Comment: remove `flex: auto`?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `flex: auto;` from the rule for `.wrapper p`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.wrapper p {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
  <p>D</p>
  <p>E</p>
  <p>F</p>
  <p>G</p>
  <p>H</p>
  <p>I</p>
  <p>J</p>
  <p>K</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `flex:auto;` from your code.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.wrapper p {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
  <p>D</p>
  <p>E</p>
  <p>F</p>
  <p>G</p>
  <p>H</p>
  <p>I</p>
  <p>J</p>
</div>
```